# vb2010express Subroutine running randomly

Tags: vb.net

I'm making the retro arcade game 'Asteroids', and am having a problem with the destruction of asteroids when contacting a bullet.

When I load the game, all the asteroids will appear, but throughout the course of a few minutes, they will all randomly be blown up. I have a subroutine, 'AsteroidDestroyer' which destroys an asteroid depending on what is transmitted to it.

```
Sub AsteroidDestroyer(ByVal Asteroid As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox)
    If Asteroid Is picLrgAsteroid100 Then
        picMedAsteroid110.Image = MedAsteroid
        picMedAsteroid110.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        picMedAsteroid110.Size = New Size(40, 40)
        picMedAsteroid110.Shape(100, 0)
        picMedAsteroid110.Top = picLrgAsteroid100.Top + (picLrgAsteroid100.Height / 2)
        picMedAsteroid110.Left = picLrgAsteroid100.Left + (picLrgAsteroid100.Width / 2)
        picMedAsteroid110.Tag = "Asteroid"
        Me.Controls.Add(picMedAsteroid110)
        picMedAsteroid120.Image = MedAsteroid
        picMedAsteroid120.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        picMedAsteroid120.Size = New Size(40, 40)
        picMedAsteroid120.Shape(100, 0)
        picMedAsteroid120.Top = picLrgAsteroid100.Top + (picLrgAsteroid100.Height / 2)
        picMedAsteroid120.Left = picLrgAsteroid100.Left + (picLrgAsteroid100.Width / 2)
        picMedAsteroid120.Tag = "Asteroid"
        Me.Controls.Add(picMedAsteroid120)
        picMedAsteroid130.Image = MedAsteroid
        picMedAsteroid130.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        picMedAsteroid130.Size = New Size(40, 40)
        picMedAsteroid130.Shape(100, 0)
        picMedAsteroid130.Top = picLrgAsteroid100.Top + (picLrgAsteroid100.Height / 2)
        picMedAsteroid130.Left = picLrgAsteroid100.Left + (picLrgAsteroid100.Width / 2)
        picMedAsteroid130.Tag = "Asteroid"
        Me.Controls.Add(picMedAsteroid130)
        Me.Controls.Remove(picLrgAsteroid100)
    End if
End Sub
```

As I said, this will randomly occur, and everything will get blown up eventually. The only places AsteroidDestroyer is mentioned in the entirety of my code is in this subroutine, and in my collision detection subroutine.

```
Private Sub CollisionDetection_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CollisionDetection.Tick
    Dim Asteroids() = {picLrgAsteroid100, picLrgAsteroid200, picLrgAsteroid300, picLrgAsteroid400, picLrgAsteroid500}
    'Stores all asteroids, used for testing collision for all asteroids
    For Each PictureBox In Asteroids
        'For all asteroids
        If PictureBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picBullet1.Bounds) Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(picBullet1)
            AsteroidDestroyer(PictureBox)
        ElseIf PictureBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picBullet2.Bounds) Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(picBullet2)
            AsteroidDestroyer(PictureBox)
        ElseIf PictureBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picBullet3.Bounds) Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(picBullet3)
            AsteroidDestroyer(picBullet3)
        End If
        'If it intersects with a bullet
        'Remove the bullet, and transmit to break apart the asteroid
    Next
End Sub
```

Any suggestions as to what's going on here? I'm not overly familiar with this, but what I know is...

- The subroutine is only mentioned in the collision detection code
- It occurs before firing any bullets, which should be required for collision
- The bullets don't 'exist', and aren't added until I press space to fire

Comment: set a *breakpoint* in your destroyer routine, when it stops examine the *call stack* to see what invoked it   Consult MSDN for the details on the key words.  I suspect that timer is involved.

Comment: Computers do very little "randomly". It's far more likely that you simply do not understand the pattern of what's going on.